# Hibernate filter apply every time entity is loaded

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a multilanguage software. Using filters in hibernate, I want that every time an entity is accessed, only translation with the specific language being load.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "province")
@FilterDef(name = "findByLanguage", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "language", type = "string")})
public class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    @Filter(name = "findByLanguage", condition = "language = :language")
    private Set<ProvinceTranslation> translations;
}
```

This works as I expected for province, But `Country` has also a list of translations, and I want that `CountryTranslation` list is also contains only specified language when I load a province. But this code does not work:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
@FilterDef(name = "findByLanguage", parameters = {@ParamDef(name = "language", type = "string")})
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private List<Province> provinces;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    @Filter(name = "findByLanguage", condition = "language = :language")
    private Set<CountryTranslation> translations;
}
```

So if I load `Country` directly everything is ok, But if I load `Province` and access `Country` inside it, loading `Country` is different and `@Filter` is being ignored. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure you're supposed to redefine a filter for each entity. Have you tried giving different names to the filter definitions for `Country` and `Province`? You can then activate them both and see if that changes things

Comment: @crizzis I tried it and still doesn't work